# How do I merge the results from proc sql count into one table?

Tags: sas

I used proc sql to count the number of observations in 4 different tables. Now how do I merge these 4 results so that I get one nice table? Thanks.

Comment: Show the code you are using now.  What did you try to do to combine them?  In what way did it not work?

Comment: Use @Richard's solution to avoid this in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Proc sql;

Create table counts as

Select count(*) as count, "t1" as source from t1

Union select count(*) as count, "t2" as source from t2

Union select count(*) as count, "t3" as source from t3

Union select count(*) as count, "t4" as source from t4;

Quit;`
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL DICTIONARY.TABLES might be what you want.

Example:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select libname, memname, nobs
  from dictionary.tables
  where libname = 'SASHELP'
    and upcase(memname) in ('CARS', 'CLASS', 'AIR', 'BASEBALL')
  ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to merge tables in SAS, and you can even count the observations all in a single step. Assuming you have four tables with one row and dataset each, you can do a simple `merge` step. For example:

```
data count1;
    n_obs1 = 100;
run;

data count2;
    n_obs2 = 200;
run;

data want;
    merge count1 count2;
run;
```

You could also do everything in a single SQL step.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select nobs_1, nobs_2
        from (select count(*) as nobs_1 from sashelp.cars)
           , (select count(*) as nobs_2 from sashelp.class)
    ;
quit;
```